# Unchecking answers

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I wonder whether unchecking an answer causes some loss of reputation to the answerer.

A user that I hold in great esteem for his skills as a brilliant mathematician and a clear and patient teacher has asked me to uncheck one of his answers in order to give the question more evidence and opportunities to get an answer even more detailed than his, but I do not want to damage him in any way. I think that losing reputation is a damage because, by losing reputation, one loses opportunities to start bounties.

Does unchecking an answer cause a loss of "rep"? I thank you for any answer!

Comment: Really you should not worry about this, in general and even less if they asked you so. Chances are they have more points than they ever want to use for bounties regardless. And, in any case, I think you should honor their request.

Comment: Hi Davide, sorry for off-topically pinging you here, I have stopped being active on Physics SE (you can read why on my profile there). Technical questions containing LaTex that involve derivations, calculations, etc you better ask on PhysicsForums or Quora where they are better received. Math SE is an ok place for them too, but most physicists dont answer things on Math SE ...

Comment: @Dilaton I heartily thank you! I have asked [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-Amp%C3%A8res-law-be-rigorously-proved-from-the-Biot-Savart-law) on Quora. Thank you for suggesting PhysicsForums too!

Comment: @Dilaton My last question on PSE has been migrated [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1655828/a-commutation-between-curl-and-integral). I hope I will never see comments scoffing at me because I'm convinced that $(\mathbf{l},r_i)\mapsto\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l})}{\|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}\|^3}$, with $\mathbf{r}=\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i \hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$, isn't continuous at the points where $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{l}$, like  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1655828/a-commutation-between-curl-and-integral#comment3376869_1655828), at least not here...

Comment: and also notice that the scoffing user, also a down/close voter, also is the person that [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35467/discussion-on-question-by-self-teachingdavide-rigorous-proof-of-amperes-law-fro) me to ask the question about the single steps I don't understand.

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide yes I know him ... ;-). To me it seems $I$ is not continuous indeed for $r=l$ indeed. Math SE is certainly a friendlier place for your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unaccepting the answer will remove the 15 reputation points earned by having an accepted answer. Of course, if you later decide to accept the answer again, those 15 reputation points will be returned/re-given. (Also, the two reputation points *you* earned by accepting the answer will also be removed.)

[Read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/214632) for a list of ways reputation can be earned/lost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the unaccept will undo the awarding of the 15 points; it will result in a -15.

(This assumes things are not in CW.)